# AWS createPresignedPost methods returns credential error during file upload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3

my problem is with the credential error for aws createPresignedPost method in NodeJS. Here is my code block:

```
export async function getCognitoCredentials() {
  const stsClient = new STSClient({ region: 'eu-west-1' })

  const assumeRoleCommand = new AssumeRoleCommand({
    RoleArn: `arn:aws:iam::${id}:role/new-iam-cross-account-role`,
    RoleSessionName: 'serviceName',
    DurationSeconds: 3600,
  })

  const assumeRoleResponse = await stsClient.send(assumeRoleCommand)

  return {
    accessKeyId: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials?.AccessKeyId!,
    secretAccessKey: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials?.SecretAccessKey!,
    sessionToken: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials?.SessionToken!,
  }
}

const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: 'eu-west-1', credentials: getCognitoCredentials })

console.log(s3Client)
const { url, fields } = await createPresignedPost(s3Client, {
    Bucket: 'bucketName',
    Key: path,
    Conditions: [
        ['content-length-range', min, max],
        ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', 'image/'],
    ],
    Expires: 600,
})
console.log('url >>>', url)
console.log('fields >>>', fields)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Credential is missing
```

I have checked the credentials and it should be true. I did not understand the reason I get the error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more context here? Where is ID coming from? What is getCognitoCredentials? A complete failing example would be helpful here

Comment: getCognitoCredentials is the function which returns authentication details as in the method. ID is the account id given by AWS web interface. I also noticed that error is returning right after AssumeRoleCommand function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

`getCognitoCredentials` is a function, but you're not calling it:

```
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: 'eu-west-1', credentials: getCognitoCredentials })
```

Try calling the function and see if you get the same error.

```
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: 'eu-west-1', credentials: getCognitoCredentials() })
```

Comment: This is not the case where problem occurs. "Credential is missing" error is thrown in line above:

const assumeRoleResponse = await stsClient.send(assumeRoleCommand)

Comment: Are you authenticated to STS?

Comment: I think I am. I am able to authenticate and get token via cognito

Comment: What local credentials do you have set? Are you using a shared credentials file?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is related to my local credentials cause AssumeRoleCommand function returns the error. All I have are just three parameters which are RoleArn, RoleSessionName and Duration. I do not even use credentials in here. If i am then I do not know where to place it.

Comment: You can't assume a role without being authenticated, otherwise anyone could assume your roles. Ideally you would not be assuming roles in your code in first place. Instead you would be creating Cognito users, assigning roles to them, and signing in. But, if you must assume a role, you need IAM creds. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-format.html